# I want to typecast in SQL to numeric(5,1) in order to have values round to one decimal point - however, this fails to work

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, casting, subquery

I'm currently calculating 'fizziness' which is equal to volume * fizzyfactor / 100.

However, the values become very long floats. I want to round them to one decimal point.

When typecasting with numeric, it still has the same output. Why? How can I fix this ?

Here is my query:

```
create or replace view fizz(softdrink, store, fizziness)
as
select name, store, (volume * fizzyfactor/100)::decimal(5,1) as fizziness
```

And my output looks like so:
[image: Column under 'fizziness' looks like this instead of having one decimal point]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: I cannot reproduce, you will need to provide more information(**as update to question**) 1) Postgres version 2) In `psql` what the result of `\d fizz` is? 3) The result of `select name, store, (volume * fizzyfactor/100)::decimal(5,1) as fizziness`.  **Do not add information as images**, copy and paste as text into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you cant use the SQL Round() function?
if not you could use this query to round to exactly one decimal point

```
create or replace view fizz(softdrink, store, fizziness)
as
select name, store, Round((volume * fizzyfactor/100),1) as fizziness
```

you can read more about the Round() function here:

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-math-functions/postgresql-round/

Comment: Don't link to SQL Server pages when OP is using Postgresql. (Too often differences between products.)

Answer (score 0):

> When typecasting ... it still has the same output. Why?

Please recheck your *data base*

See the example below working with `::decimal(5,1)` *as expected*; same result obtained with `round`

```
with dt as ( 
select * from (values 
(13, .7),
(12345, .1345)
) dt(volume, fizzyfactor)
)
select volume, fizzyfactor,
(volume * fizzyfactor/100) as fizziness,
(volume * fizzyfactor/100)::decimal(5,1) as fizziness_cast,
round((volume * fizzyfactor/100),1) as fizziness_round
from dt;

volume|fizzyfactor|fizziness             |fizziness_cast|fizziness_round|
------+-----------+----------------------+--------------+---------------+
    13|        0.7|0.09100000000000000000|           0.1|            0.1|
 12345|     0.1345|   16.6040250000000000|          16.6|           16.6|
```